# Colour specific countries on a worldmap and adding mappoint cities

Tags: r, maps, r-highcharter

I want to design a worldmap to show from which country and which city the participants to my survey come from. I used the highcharter package.

First part is : colour the countries --> it worked well ! A scale is created from 0 to 1.
Second part is : adding the cities --> the points are created but the countries colored in blue disappeared ! The scale has changed and is now induced from cities.

I try to change the order of my code but nothing is working.

````
library(dplyr)
library(maps)
library(magrittr)
# I use the dataset called iso3166 from the {maps} package and rename it date

dat <- iso3166
head(dat)

# I rename the variable a3 by iso-a3

dat <- rename(dat, "iso-a3" = a3)
head(dat)

# I create a vector with the countries I want to colour 

part1X_countries <- c("CHE", "FRA", "USA", "GBR", "CAN", "BRA")

dat$part1X <- ifelse(dat$`iso-a3` %in% part1X_countries, 1, 0)
head(dat)

# I add the name of cities with geographical coordinates

cities <- data.frame(
  name = c("St Gallen", "Fort Lauderdale", "Paris", "Nottingham", "Winnipeg", "Chicago", "Leeds", "Montréal", "New Rochelle", "São Paulo", "Saint-Genis-Pouilly", "Canterbury"),
  lat = c(47.42391, 26.122438, 48.866667, 52.950001, 49.8955, 41.881832, 53.801277, 45.5016889, 40.9232, -23.5489, 46.24356, 51.279999),
  lon = c(9.37477, -80.137314, 2.333333, -1.150000, -97.1383, -87.623177, -1.548567, -73.567256, -73.7793, -46.6388, 6.02119, 1.080000))

# I create my worldmap with countries and cities

worldmap <- hcmap(
  map = "custom/world-highres3", # high resolution world map
  data = dat, # name of dataset
  value = "part1X",
  joinBy = "iso-a3",
  showInLegend = FALSE, # hide legend
  download_map_data = TRUE
) %>%
  hc_add_series(
  data = cities, 
  type = "mappoint",
  name = "Cities"
) %>%
  hc_title(text = "Representation of participants by country")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a colorkey and add a color axis for the `hcmap`. The below code keeps the colors from the countries and has the name of the countries added on top as black map points.

```
worldmap <- hcmap(
  map = "custom/world-highres3", # high resolution world map
  data = dat, # name of dataset
  value = "part1X",
  joinBy = "iso-a3",
  colorKey = "value",
  showInLegend = F, # hide legend
  download_map_data = TRUE)  %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(min = min(dat$part1X), 
               max = max(dat$part1X)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(
    data = cities, 
    type = "mappoint",
    name = "Cities",
    dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.name}'),
    latField = "lat",
    longField = "lon",
    # color = "color"
    valueField = "part1X"
  ) %>%
  hc_title(text = "Representation of participants by country")
worldmap
```

Comment: Woow nice @maupagas ! It's working : ) I actually found a lesser solution yesterday changing the binary in the part1X code (1000, 0). Your solution is much better ! And I found a way to change the color of the map points. But I still have a problem, do you know why some cities are not written (like Paris) ?

Comment: This is due to the allowOverlap option of dataLabels which is defaulted as False. Use `dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.name}', allowOverlap = T, padding = 0)`  to show all the names and as close as possible to the data point with the padding = 0. 
The issue however is that it looks very cluttered. Best solution would be if the names can be somehow repelled like the geom_repel in ggplot but not sure how to do that.